# Three.js: Cannot identify intersected objects by raycaster (.gtlf 3D-Object's)

Tags: three.js, dom-events

I'm working on a scene with three.js and imported .gtlf models via THREE.GLTFLoader(). I want to attach attributes to the objects and later work with those whenever an event occurs regarding those objects. But my problem is that the returned intersections by the raycaster do not carry the attributes added to the objects. Furthermore, I cannot identify which object was returned by the raycaster (for example by a obj.name attribute I attached beforehand, since the returned intersections are not 3DObjects anymore as they are when added to the scene).

How can I precisely identify which (gltf) object was returned by the raycaster?

For gemoetry objects it works perfectly fine and attributes are attached when returned from the raycaster, but for the loaded models (gltf) it's not working, even after using the "userData" attribute that aims for the purpose of carrying information, the attribute is empty afterwards.

```
gltfLoader.load('./assets/simple_shelf/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {
    shelf = gltf.scene.children[0];
    shelf.userData.direction = "test string";
    scene.add(shelf);
});
//console.log(shelf.userData.direction) shows it correctly, but returned 
//by raycaster on events (e.g. mousemove), userData is empty

function onMouseMove(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.width - rect.left ) ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top) ) * 2 + 1;

                raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse,camera);
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
                for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++){
                    console.log(intersects[i]);
                }
            }
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

I want to somehow exactly identify the object the raycaster returns, i.e. trigger the events. Hence I want to add attributes and retrieve them on event occurance.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add your raycasting code? We'd need to see how you're accessing the data of the intersected object to see if you're doing something wrong or not.

Comment: Added it. The raycasting itself works perfectly fine though, the objects are returned on mouseover events. I think the problem lies within the fact that my imported models as .gtlf are a differend type as the other Mesh'es i have with BoxGeometry, MeshLamberMaterial, ... all hovered objects (both Meshes and .gltf 3d Objects) are correctly returned, but only the Meshes which are not externally loaded models do keep the assigned attributes.

Comment: How is your `.gltf` structured? I'm thinking `gltf.scene.children[0]` could probably be a [Group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group) and your raycasting result is a child Mesh inside that group. So maybe you're assigning the `userData` property to a parent object of your meshes.

Comment: It's been a while. Did you freeprogrammer233 find a way to detect Object3D and Group from loaded 3D models? I am just trying to solve this thing in my fresh starting project.